# JavaScript is not working in this.response in XHR

Tags: javascript, css, xml, animation, xmlhttprequest

I have two questions for this code today:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName !== "A" || !event.target.href) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  document.body.style.opacity = 0
  var res = new XMLHttpRequest();
  res.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.querySelector('html').innerHTML =
      this.response;
  });
  res.open("GET", event.target.href);
  res.send();
});
```

How to insert the animations `document.body.style.opacity = 0;` and `document.body.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {`
 (now it's not working)

Why isn't the result of the `this.response;` not reading JS? (Page loads without JS).

Comment: [HTML5 specifies that a script tag inserted with innerHTML should not execute.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)

Comment: @James is right. You should create a new script tag with `document.createElement('script')`, and then put the script inside the script tag. For it to work, the Content Security Policy of the page needs to allow inline script-src.

Comment: I still don't know how to do it...

Comment: I forgot to mention how to change the URL so that it changes completely (now it stays the previous one)